Is the Day of arrival included in a stay?
Unless otherwise specified a tourist can stay in Canada for 6 months. But is the day of arrival included? For a simple example, a person arrives in Canada on January 1st, when should they have to leave Canada so they won’t extend their stay: Jun 30th or Jul 1st?

While these are legal questions, you'll often find more expertise in [travel.se].

The Immigration and Refugee Protection Regulations provide

183 (2) Subject to subsections (3) to (5), the period authorized for the stay of a temporary resident is six months [...]
183 (3) The period authorized for the stay of a temporary resident begins on [...] the day on which they enter Canada.
183 (4) The period authorized for a temporary resident’s stay ends on the earliest of [...] (d) the day on which the period authorized under subsection (2) ends [...]

Section 28 of the Interpretation Act is more pertinent and should be applied mutatis mutandis to include the date of arrival without impacting the end date.

28 Where there is a reference to a period of time consisting of a number of months after or before a specified day, the period is calculated by
(a) counting forward or backward from the specified day the number of months, without including the month in which that day falls;
(b) excluding the specified day; and
(c) including in the last month counted under paragraph (a) the day that has the same calendar number as the specified day or, if that month has no day with that number, the last day of that month.

See also s. 27(3):

(3) Where a time is expressed to begin or end at, on or with a specified day, or to continue to or until a specified day, the time includes that day.

This would mean that for a foreign national who enters Canada on January 1, the six-month authorized period of stay should end on July 1, the last day during which the foreign national must leave Canada. For someone who enters Canada on August 31, the last day of authorized stay should be the last day of February of the next year (either 28 or 29, depending if the year in question is a leap year).
As a practical matter though, you should be conservative and do not plan your stay too close to a deadline in any case.

Section 28 of the Interpretation Act explains how to understand periods specified in months from a date:

(c) including in the last month counted under paragraph (a) the day that has the same calendar number as the specified day or, if that month has no day with that number, the last day of that month.

So it includes July 1, since has the same number as the arrival date Jan 1.

No
The answer is in s27 of the Interpretation Act, specifically subsection (4):

(4) Where a time is expressed to begin after or to be from a specified day, the time does not include that day.


so, what is the end date? Jun 30, Jul 1st or July 2nd (because that's the 183rd day of the year)

That section is for periods specified in days, not months. See my answer for months.
